# Recursive CTE going in Infinite Loop when Parent child ID's are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have used recursive CTE to get parent child relationship but when Parent and child id's are same (Coming from 3 different table) CTE is going on infinite loop.

Process Table:

```
id  name    ParentName  ParentID    LevelId IndustryId``
1   Billing Serve            1           3      1
1   Serve   CORE             1           2      1
1   CORE    Retail           1           1      1
1   Retail  NULL             0           0      1
```

Inventory Table:

```
RowID   IndustryId  BFuncName
1               1   Asses effectiveness of regulatory strategy
2               1   Brand and customer strategy
3               1   Brand Strategy
4               1   Billing
5               1   Brand management
6               1   Context & Content Management
7               1   Compensation Guidelines
8               1   Customer Contact
9               1   COMPLIANCE
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @CurrentRow int SET @CurrentRow=0 
DECLARE @IndustryId INT set @IndustryId=1

WHILE @CurrentRow<=@RowsToProcess 
BEGIN

;with inventorytableexpression as 
( 
select id, parentid,Name ,LevelId --------from Processes 
from Process where Lower(Name) = (SELECT Lower(BFuncName) 
FROM Inventory 
WHERE RowID = 1 AND IndustryId=@IndustryId) 
AND IndustryId=@IndustryId 
union all 
select C.id, C.parentid,c.Name,c.LevelId 
from Process c join inventorytableexpression p on c.id = P.parentid AND IndustryId=@IndustryId

)

Select * from inventorytableexpression option (maxrecursion 0)

SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1

END
```

Results:

```
id  parentid    Name    LevelId
1   1          Billing  3
1   1          Serve    2
1   1          CORE     1
1   0          Retail   0
```

Comment: Does the picture you include represent the desired results or what?

Comment: *"but when Parent and child id's are same CTE is going on infinite loop"* Why would you not expect it to? You're effectively joining Parent ID to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, which has a Parent ID of 1, so you're joining it to ID 1, .... What you have is called a circular reference. Something shouldn't be the parent of itself.

Comment: It will definitely throw an error as it will not allow more than 100 recursion. Not sure what result you want. Please updates your question with proper details.

Comment: These child values are coming from different tables  which is having autogenerated key... And I can identify on the basis of level only.Level 0 indicates root and last leaf node...